# How do I get my bookmarks code of Chrome?

Tags: html, json, google-chrome, web-crawler, bookmarks

I'd like to redesign my bookmarks data in my small project.

So I need to get my bookmarks code (is API?).

Is there any solution to extract codes of my own bookmarks (link, folder...) ouf of Google Chrome?

Thanks!

Comment: see: [Chrome Bookmarks API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/bookmarks/)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.